# how to let webpage inside webbrowser control trigger vb.net function of windows form?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I put a webbrowser control in my windows form application and I would like my visual basic.net script to know if a button is clicked inside the webpage that is loaded by the webbrowser control.
I suppose there must be a way to do this, so far I know how to access  document elements by ID but i dont know how to know if their events are fired.
thanks for your help!

```
Imports Gecko
Public Class Form1
    Public myBrowser As GeckoWebBrowser
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize("c:\xulrunner")
        myBrowser = New GeckoWebBrowser()
        myBrowser.Parent = Me
        myBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        myBrowser.Navigate("example.com")
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' MessageBox.Show(myBrowser.Document.GetElementById("divID").TextContent())
    End Sub
    Private Sub divclick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles myBrowser.Document.GetElementById("divID").Click
        'codes that i need to be run
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: One thing is VBScript and another thing is VB.NET (which does not create scripts). Also with VB.NET you can create a desktop application (winforms or WPF) or a web-application (ASP, Silverlight). You can put a webbrowser control in any of these options. The behaviour (even the exact control) is different in any case, please, be as precise as you can in your exact conditions. Also, please, post the code you have written so far.

Comment: i added my code, its a windows form application using Mozilla Gecko browsing engine

Comment: You don't need to add an external webbrowser control. .NET has its own control (WebBrowser). Steven Doggart's answer is precisely applied to the .NET control. Do some research to know how to implement it (works more or less like the one in your code) or ask Steven or be more precise in your question and ask for help with GeckoWebBrowser.

Answer (score 2):

You say that you know how to get the document elements by ID.  Once you have an `HtmlElement` object, you can add event handlers to its events.  For instance:

```
AddHandler myHtmlElement.Click, AddressOf MyElementClicked
```

Then the `MyElementClicked` method would be called every time that element in the web page is clicked:

```
Private Sub MyElementClicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As HtmlElementEventArgs)
    ' ...
End Sub
```

Typically you would add the event handlers to the HTML elements in the `DocumentCompleted` event handler of the web browser control.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not familiar with the Gecko browser control and I can't immediately find any documentation on it to see what that `GetElementById` method returns, so I can't really help you any further.